# Combining ImageCropper with MediaPicker in Umbraco 7

Tags: image, editor, umbraco, media, crop

As requested in [this](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/using-umbraco-7/66509-image-cropper-can-not-pick-from-media) thread on our.umbraco, i want to create a new property editor, that allows for the content editor to select an image both from their local hard-drive and the media archive, to then be cropped right in the content section. Basically combining two already existing property editors.

This image gives a general idea about what i want to achieve:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElU5k.png

Right now it is possible to use the image cropper on the images in the media section, but it would be more user friendly to have this functionality in the content section.

I am quite new to Umbraco and creating custom property editors, but I would like to know if this is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure why people like the ImageCropper data type. You can just [choose what size image](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper#mvc-view-example-to-output-create-custom-crops-in-this-case-forc) to render on the front end using something like `@image.GetCropUrl(width: 100, height: 100)` where image is a media item of type `IPublishedContent`. This means that the Umbraco editor just has  to upload a sufficiently large photo which then you can crop to use anywhere on the site

Comment: @Harvey ImageCropper allows a content editor to control exactly each crop required for a site design, including automatic cropping via point of interest, and manual adjustment of individual crops.  'Blind' cropping is going to get you in trouble. ;)

Comment: @sprintstar My above posted method is another way of using the ImageCropper and does not use "blind" cropping as it also relies on a point of interest as set on the media item. I was specifically saying that the ImageCropper data type sucks.

The only instance where that data type may be more useful would be if you want to have multiple different points of interests but I'm not sure what the use case for that would be.